# Cookie expiring date not working C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a cookie which expires in 30 days..

**Here is code in c#

e.UserID --> username, 
e.rememberMe --> true**

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                                                        "UserID",
                                                        DateTime.Now,
                                                        DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
                                                        e.rememberMe,
                                                        e.UserID,
                                                        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
                // Encrypt the ticket.
                string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                // Create the cookie.
                Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
```

**But in chrome the cookie store upto browser session ends**
[image]

Any idea

Comment: updated my question..

Comment: what you do with e.rememberMe in your class??

Comment: rememberMe is checkBox in client side .. where it represents isPersistent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should set the `Expires` property of the cookie object, because the cookie has no knowledge whatsoever of what you put inside it:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(
    new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket) {
        Expires = ticket.Expiration
    });
```